# DSolve argument error for no reason. Why?

Tags: differential-equations

I entered the following lines into mathematica to solve the diff eq $$y' = x^3 -4y^3$$ subject to $y(0) = 1$ and it gave me an argument error. Any help?

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == x^3 - 4*y[x]^3, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

Comment: Your code does not give an error on my computer (I use version 10). *Mathematica* cannot solve it, but I have no erros whatsoever.

Comment: What error specifically? You might have lingering definitions, in which case you need to clear or quit your kernel and try again. When I ran, this, it ran fine, although it didn't actually find a solution. Are you sure that this differential equation has a closed form solution?

Comment: @mattiav27 Well, `DSolve[]` can't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DSolve can not solve it. I try `LaplaceTransform`:

```
ode = y'[x] == x^3 - 4 y[x]^3;
ic = y[0] == 1;
deq = LaplaceTransform[ode, x, s] /. Rule @@ ic /. HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a
```

[image]

```
sol = y[x] /. First@Solve[deq, y[x]] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[sol, s, x];
```

InverseLaplaceTransform is overwhelmed. It remains only NDSolve:

```
nsol = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[y[x] /. nsol, {x, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]